Laravel backpack 6 unable to load theme tabler from CDN
I have been having issues for the past 24hours where my project (Laravel 11/ Backpack 6) are not able to fetch css from CDN. I noticed the issue in both local dev machine and my online staging server. Anyone experiencing the same issue? Any ideas? Seems like a CDN issue..




Please add relevant code snippet

There is no specific code, the problem is site wide

I can relate... the CDN is causing the issue. I'm experiencing the slow response. Here is how I solved it by caching it locally.
Add BASSET_DEV_MODE=false to your .env and run php artisan basset:cache.

This issue is indeed related to theme tabler. It can be fixed by uninstalling the theme with:
composer remove backpack/theme-tabler

and reinstalling it with:
composer require backpack/theme-tabler


tried this, it doesnt work for me
